# Randomly fill fixed number of cells in a two dimensional grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to make JavaScript Minesweeper and I've got some problems in `pushBombs` function, I guess. I'm trying to put bombs in array, sometimes it puts exact number that is said but sometimes it puts less number.

My questions:

1. When condition is true it puts bomb in array but when it's false it passes this itaration or looks for another index in array that is true?
2. Math.random() returns different values in condition and in code block.
3. It puts bomb where it already was but then why?

```js
var grid = {
    _grid: [],

    createGrid: function (c) {
        for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            this._grid.push([]);
            for (var a = 0; a < c; a++) {
                this._grid[i][a] = 'Empty';
            }
        }
    },

    pushBombs: function (b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            if (this._grid[Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid.length - 1))][Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid.length - 1))] == 'Empty') {
                this._grid[Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid.length - 1))][Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid.length - 1))] = 'Bomb';
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: The cell you are checking for empty is not necessarily the cell you are setting as bomb, as you are calling random again instead of saviing x,y as coordinates and access same positions

Comment: a major issue with your question is that your title doesn't explain the problem you actually have; and you're asking way too many questions without referring to the programming construct you're having an issue with.  Think of it this way, would you google for "Need JavaScript Help" and expect to find a solution to your problem? If not, you should change your title to what you would search google for to find an answer to your problem. Yes, this means putting a bit more effort into the formulation of your question, but that's what separates Stack Overflow from mere forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you call Math.random() you are going to get a different value. Assuming that during your code, you want to be looking at the same slot in both the check and in the assignment, you would want to only call that once for each axis of your grid. Below, I'm calling them xx and yy.

```
pushBombs: function (b) {
   for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
      var xx = Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid.length - 1));
      var yy = Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid.length - 1)); 
      if (this._grid[xx][yy] == 'Empty') {
        this._grid[xx][yy] = 'Bomb';
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
Something you might want to think about is that, this code assumes that both dimensions of your grid are equal in length. Based on the createGrid() method it looks like that is the case. Thinking ahead you may choose to have a rectangular grid, in which case, this pushBombs() method would break. One option is to store the X and Y lengths in so that the xx and yy can correctly randomize their values. Alternatively, I might suggest changing the code above slightly to use:

```
    //randmomize the length of the first dimension        
    var xx = Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid.length - 1));
    //randomize the second dimension. Notice, this is looking at the length 
    //of the first item in the grid (which is your second dimension).
    var yy = Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid[0].length - 1));
```

**EDIT 2**
If you want to ensure that you always get the exact number of bombs, you should use a while loop as @PierreDuc suggested:

```
    while(b > 0) {
      var xx = Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid.length - 1));
      var yy = Math.round(Math.random() * (this._grid[0].length - 1)); 
      if (this._grid[xx][yy] == 'Empty') {
        this._grid[xx][yy] = 'Bomb';
        b--;
      }
    }
```

Note though that if the value of *b* is greater than the number of **Empty** slots, this will turn into an infinite loop.

Comment: This also won't work. Because there is a chance it will not give the proper amount of bombs. Better use a `while` loop with inside the `if bomb is empty` statement the incrementation :)

Comment: @PierreDuc - good catch. I updated it

Comment: I was just thinking about that infinite loop as well, but i see you already caught up on it. Nice one

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, it's working.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as "the answer" if it solved your issue :-)